# How to quick duck in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When you duck in GS:GO there is penalty or an after effect that makes you slower at second duck. But in this video the delay does not appear to be affecting them. How can they do it?

@3:57

Comment: hmm maybe demo files show us in this way and the actual duck was slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know this could be related to how the "spectator" works in game engine - f.ex. join the game as spectator and follow some player - when he reloads his weapon sometimes You won't notice any animation - just played sound - this probably works the same way... I do not have a source for this, but read it somewhere on the steampowered forums...